# oracle10 windows cx_Oracle Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle

Tags: python, windows, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to set up my python script in a new server i'm migrating to but whenever i'm trying to connect to the DB with the script i get the following error

```
dbHost = 'xxxxxx'
dbPort = xxxx
dbServiceName = 'xxx.xxxx.com'
dbUser = 'xxxx'
dbPass = 'xxxx'
dnsTns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(dbHost, dbPort, dbServiceName).replace('SID','SERVICE_NAME')
dbCon = cx_Oracle.connect(dbUser, dbPass, dnsTns)

>>> dbCon = cx_Oracle.connect(dbUser, dbPass, dnsTns)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle
```

I can use sqlplus from command line using the same TNS user and pass with no problems but can't get it to work on the script

My path variable has the oracle client folder set up like the previous server (C:\oracle\bin).

TNS_ADMIN variable is set to "C:\oracle\NETWORK\ADMIN"
tried using ORACLE_HOME to C:\oracle too

Oracle client is 10 same as server
windows version 64bit
cx_Oracle module 5.1.3 installed using pip
python is 2.7

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a newer client (at least 11.2) with the newer version of cx_Oracle (6.1). It should provide a better error message. The earlier versions of cx_Oracle simply gave up if creating the Oracle environment failed. Newer versions attempt to get the underlying error.

Comment: would love to, but my company server is oracle10 so we use that client version because of that so i can't...

Comment: Understood. If you can use it even temporarily (instant client is a simple unzip which you can then delete afterwards) you might be able to discover the source of the problem. Otherwise, good luck! Some configuration issue is preventing the connection from taking place.